# I NEED YOUR HELP URGENTLY Bitcoins

Tags: transactions, wallet, blockchain.info, fraud

I really need your help on this. It has stated in my wallet that i've received my bitcoins of 1.182691BTC on 29/05/18. This's my wallet address: muFjdWSy2DKStSP2gUH2aHZq6kRBva8ZDV it stated on the insight.bitpay.com. It stated confirmed. However, i can't send out to another wallet address as it stated insufficient funds. Please advise me what should i do? Is it a scam? I really need the money soon. My mum is in icu & needed the money soon. I got into mining because i want to earn more money to help my mum.

My transaction ID is b2898b8c5f5f01f573e768ec21fc4f15c1e433e7255960fb71551f06cec36651. It seems that my transaction confirmed. What should I do next? I’m stuck.

[image]

---

I was told to create a bitpay wallet & tick Testnet & Single Address. And i have received 1.182691BTC on 29/05/18. I wanted to send this bitcoins to localbitcoins to sell my bitcoins, but i was prompt that it's insufficient. I'm wanted to sent out the whole bitcoins i've to my other wallet apps. When i see the insight.bitpay.com, my bitcoins is stated in Total Received & Final Balance. But it's not under Total Sent. And indicated (U) - Output is unspent. This money is very urgent for me, i need it for my mum illness.

---

What should i do now? There's nothing i can do right? It's a scam right? Now i'm in huge debts. The miner said i will not be able to use them because they're being held in escrow by the bitpay servers due to bit large use of bitcoin payment. Until i pay USD $1000 then they will ask bitpay servers to release it so i can use it.

---

Yes i do have all the conversations & the profile of the fake miner. He still said he's a christian that won't scam people. He knows my mum illness so he definitely won't scam.

Comment: What wallet software are you using? How much money are you trying to send?

Comment: I was told to create a bitpay wallet & tick Testnet & Single Address. And i have received 1.182691BTC on 29/05/18. I wanted to send this bitcoins to localbitcoins to sell my bitcoins, but i was prompt that it's insufficient. I'm wanted to sent out the whole bitcoins i've to my other wallet apps. 

When i see the insight.bitpay.com, my bitcoins is stated in 
Total Received & Final Balance. But it's not under Total Sent. And indicated (U)  - Output is unspent. This money is very urgent for me, i need it for my mum illness.

Comment: test net, as the name suggests, is used for testing purposes and not real transactions. The main net is where you get real bitcoins... No wonder why I wasn't able to get this transaction id on any of the websites.

Comment: You received testnet Bitcoin, they are completely and absolutely worthless. You do not have any actual Bitcoin.

Comment: Whatthe. What should i do now? There's nothing i can do right? It's a scam right? Now i'm in huge debts. The miner said i will not be able to use them because they're being held in escrow by the bitpay servers due to bit large use of bitcoin payment. Until i pay USD $1000 then they will ask bitpay servers to release it so i can use it.

Comment: If u have proof of this conversation and the identity of the miner, you could take help from your local authorities. YES, it definitely was a scam.

Comment: Yes i do have all the conversations & the profile of the fake miner. He still said he's a christian that won't scam people. He knows my mum illness so he definitely won't scam.

Comment: Your "miner" is not a miner, just a con-man. Everything they say is lies to trick you out of more money.

Answer (score 3):

This is a scam.

You should report this to your local police.

However your money is gone and you will never see it again.

If you pay the scammer the $1000 they ask for, they will just come up with another reason that you need to send more money or just ignore you.