# Funds disapprearance

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, mining-profitability

I stored 0.0154 BTC in my blockchain for mining purposes and next morning I found my balance to be 000, what does that mean? Are my coins lost or stored somewhere else?

Comment: What do you mean by "Mining purposes"? Did someone tell you to deposit it?

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

> **I STORED 0.0154 BTC IN MY BLOCKCHAIN WALLET FOR MINING PURPOSE**

Mining bitcoin does not require putting bitcoin into a wallet you own.

Asking people to link their wallets to a miner is a favourite trick of conmen / scammers.

> **IN THE NEXT MORNING I FOUND MY BALANCE TO BE 000 , WHAT DOES THAT MEAN?**

If someone else knows the password to your online wallet, they can extract from it the "private key" which gives control over any bitcoin already sent to addresses in that wallet as well as any future amounts sent to addresses in that wallet (even after you change wallet passwords).

It is likely you are the victim of a conman and your money has been stolen.

---

Related questions with useful answers:

- [BTC Stolen from Blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/68697/13866)

  > A guy ... told me that I can mine for bitcoin ... Within half an hour my wallet was empty.
- [Bitcoin Mining as a Newbie (link wallet to another person's miner)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74841/13866)
- [I've been asked to share wallet credentials to participate in mining. Is that a scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66934/13866)
- [I NEED YOUR HELP URGENTLY Bitcoins](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75776/13866)